# Python3 gzip create new file which did not exist yet

Tags: python-3.x, gzip

I struggle with python3.9, maybe I'm just blind, so give me a hint please.

Accoring to documententation the following code should create a ".gz"-file.

```
import gzip
content = b"Lots of content here"
with gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Is it correct to assume that the file *file.txt.gz* does **not** exist before that operation and it **will be created** during that operation?

My code looks like:

```
import gzip

...
class FileHandler:

...

    def archive(self):
        self.content = 'Hello compressed World'
        zipFile = '/home/user/archive/test.gz'
        print(f'{zipFile}')
        with gzip.open(zipFile, 'wt') as f:
            f.write(self.content)
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fp = FileHandler()
    fp.archive()
```

I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/filehandling.py", line 55, in <module>
    fp.archive()
  File "/home/user/filehandling.py", line 46, in archive
    with gzip.open(zipFile, 'wt') as f:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/gzip.py", line 58, in open
    binary_file = GzipFile(filename, gz_mode, compresslevel)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/gzip.py", line 173, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/archive/test.gz'
```

Obvisiously the file does not exist. Why is it not created as mentioned in the documentation?
So what I am doing wrong here?

---- SOLVED ----
@Czaporka is right, I was missing a part of the path

Comment: Does `/home/user/` exist?

Comment: Looks like your indentation is off on the line following ```with gzip.open(zipFile, 'wt') as f:```

Comment: @Czaporka thank you! That was my blind spot - I changed the path in the example, because I was indeed missing a part of it.

Comment: @itprorh66 I changed the indentation of that line for sanity - in my real code it was correct.